# Is there a way to undo a Mailbox message deletion?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

If you accidentally sell something you didn't mean to, you can use the vendor Buy Back tab to recover the item without any more cost than what it was sold to you for.

But what can you do if you accidentally delete a mail from your mailbox? One that has items or credits in it? The "Delete all checked messages" and "Get all checked message attachments" are right next to each other in the interface, which similar sizes and icon emphasis, so it can be easily mistaken.

Is there any way to get back a deleted message, or at least the items/credits in one?

Comment: In patch 1.1.3, Bioware added confirmation dialogs for some permanent, expensive actions in the same patch. Maybe one day they'll add that for Delete All mail too? http://www.swtor.com/patchnotes/1.1.3/2142012

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While it isn't possible to 'undelete' a piece of mail through the UI, GM's **do** have the ability to restore lost items or credits if you open a support ticket. There is a limit to the frequency with which you can request this service (three times in a six month period), and you can expect the whole process to take several days given the current support load GM's are facing immediately after launch.

To open a ticket, click on the Question Mark (**'?'**) icon on the right hand side of the menubar at the top of your screen. You'll see a tab at the bottom labelled **Request Help**. Fill out a ticket, and submit it. You should have a response 'soon'.

*N.B. If your experience is anything like mine, your initial ticket might be closed as a bug report, or some other such nonsense that indicates it wasn't read. **In this case, submit a new ticket.** Old Republic GM's have the ability to restore items, within the limitations I noted above, but their support system is currently very overloaded, and errors do occur.*

Answer (score 2):

By yourself, likely not.  Your only hope would be to file a GM ticket and hope policy is on your side.  Useful things to include in the ticket would be who the mail was from, what was in it, roughly what time it was sent, and what time you deleted it.

In order to file a ticket, click the **?** on the top menu, and at the bottom click the tab for filing a ticket.  Be sure after you send it to click the button that none of the FAQ solved your problem in order to actually submit it.

There's no guarantee this will work, but it may be your only recourse.  If it does or does not, be sure to let us know for future reference.

Comment: Who are you referring to by "let us know"? The Gaming.SE community?

Comment: @Mufasa Yes, getting confirmation one way or another is useful.